# LARAVEL input value from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I echo the value of the database value into input type?
Here's the database variable

```
      $suppliers->supplier_name
```

And here my form text code. this code is not working...

```
   {!! Form::text('supplier_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control','value'=>'$suppliers->supplier_name')) !!}
```

I'm using laravel 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter is the value for the input, so:

```
{!! Form::text('supplier_name', $suppliers->supplier_name, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

Comment: Welcome! If it worked, don't forget to mark as accepted, to help others to find the answer.

Comment: On the left of my answer, the outlined checkmark :)